# Want to execute an API request every time a user navigates to a page in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am making an Instagram clone and I want to execute an API request to fetch data from the database every time a user clicks on the profile item in the bottom navigation bar. How can I achieve this?

The app is being built in flutter and the backend I am using is Spring boot and MySQL database.

Comment: you can follow this project's pattern: https://github.com/simplezhli/flutter_deer

Answer (score 0):

You can call API in initState.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     fetchData(); // Call your API here
  }
```

But remember that, when the user press any profile item on the bottom navigation bar, this initState may not work every time, this is due to your project structure. In that case, initstate will only work in BotoomNavigationScreen. So to call api evrytime in this scenerio, you use `VisibilityDetector`

```
VisibilityDetector(
        key: Key('Profile one page key'),
        onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
          if (visibilityInfo.visibleFraction == 1.0) {
            fetchData(); // Call your API here
          }
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Your Data'),
        ),
```